# Invoke methods with different arguments in a generic way

Tags: java

Im trying to write a generic code, so that I can **invoke methods at runtime** with different Number & Type of arguments. I have class & different methods at my disposal which I am reading from a file, along with the arguments to be passed into that particular method.

So, here's an Object array which contains values of different type -

**Object[] args = new Object[]{"aString", 1, true};**

/* based on Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Object obj, Object... args) , I have written the following method */

//"executingMethod" references the method to be executed, which one can get from Class.forName("ClassName").getDeclaredMethods(); and traversing it for the particular method.

**executingMethod.invoke(methodClassObject, args);** //and obviously it doesn't execute because at runtime it doesn't know(can't downcast) param "Type".

I don't want to pass args[0], args[1], args[2] inside executingMethod.invoke(..), as for some case the number of arguments may vary.

Any suggestions pls??

Comment: 1. Post the actual code. 2. Post exceptions you are getting. 3. From what you posted so far - you are passing a class object, instead of an instance to the `invoke` method, and that is the source of your problems.

Comment: To confirm the 3. from the npe comment, try to invoke a static method rather than an instance method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to deal with that problem:

Create the following interface

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public interface ExecutableInterface {
    void executable(String methodName);
    String getExecutableMethod();
    void setParameters(ArrayList parameters);
    ArrayList getParameters();
}
```

Now, in the class that you want to be invokable, make it implement those methods and pass the invokable method using executable and pass the parameters using the setParameter.

At runtime you get those values and call the executable method that returns getExecutableMethod. Same way with the parameters.